# How to build external C++ library with Android Studio + Gradle + NDK?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm porting C++ library to Android now. I did initial work already and got it build in Application.mk/Android.mk way.

The upcoming Java demo application for library is developing in Android Studio now. I can built everything (demo + library) together - thanks to StackOverflow community.

However I have no access to native debugging in these builds. But debugging is necessary - library is not stable enough yet. Pure console GDB debugging takes too much time for now and can consume more hours in future.

So I decided to make build with Android Studio and Gradle to use integrated debugger.

I have dedicated library module with NDK and Java (wrapper) parts.
However C/C++ source files are not under jni/ subdirectory. They are located in another directory.

Therefore I can configure Gradle to get sources from that directory.
I tried smth like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig.with {
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 10
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }

    ndk {
        moduleName = "inttalksdk"
        stl "gnustl_shared"
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        ldLibs.addAll(['log'])
    }
}

android.sources {
    main.jni.source {
        srcDirs.add(["src"])
    }
}


android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
    }
}
}
```

But AS cannot sync project even.
Error message is:

```
Gradle 'Android' project refresh failed
Error:Attempt to read a write only view of model of type 'java.lang.Object' given to rule 'android.sources { ... } @ inttalksdk/build.gradle line 24, column 5'
```

My true question is: how to add these external C/C++ files into Gradle build?

I use latest AS 2.0 + 0.7.0 beta3 experimental plugin.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in 0.7.0-beta3 experimental plugin. I reverted to 0.6.0 version.
This syntax was ok:

```
    android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDir "${project.ext.inttalksdk}/src/Components/Util/"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could also add the C++ code as a library, and then do `compile project(':my-jni-code')`

Comment: Thank you! But finally I switched to CMake support - it saved hours for me.